# How do I remove the back color or a tab control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, backcolor

[image: tab control]

I already tried putting a back color for each of the tab pages - but the extra space for the buttons of the tab control still takes the default color.

Comment: TabControl asks its Parent to draw that area.  It isn't very clear why it doesn't match the BackColor of the form.  Did you put it on a panel?  Don't.  Or reset the panel's BackColor.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the window smaller overall, to be the width of the list of tabs. Although I'm not sure if you can sacrifice the space.

Other than that, I'm not sure if you can with the default Windows Controls. Try looking into something like Infragistics, which adds on to the default windows controls with their own.